# Name of a programmer of a quantum computer?

Tags: terminology, programming, professions, computing

What is the quantum computing specific term for a "computer programmer?"

Comment: What makes you think that there is a specific term?

Comment: The specific term will be; computer programmer. I say "will be" because quantum computers don't actually exist to any usuable extent and probably never will.

Comment: Quantum computer user

Comment: The only such person I know of at the moment is our very own [Peter Shor](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/5754/peter-shor). I never really got my head around ***Shavian** = relating to [George Bernard] Shaw*, but perhaps we could just stick to the sound and ignore the spelling discrepancy.

Comment: When quantum computers become widespread enough to support *quantum hackers*, they will undoubtedly be called *quackers*.

Comment: @PeterShor - And the black hats will be *quacker crumbs*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a name that has nothing to do with EL&U. It belongs to a computer/programming community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's little more than a [buzzword](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=buzzword) but the inevitable term for it is:

**Quantum programmer**

Some people already claim to be [quantum programmers](https://www.linkedin.com/title/quantum-programmer).  Can't say that it pays much. ([65k](http://www.indeed.com/cmp/Stephen-Swan-&-Associates/jobs/Quantum-Programmer-c0d24754de35e718?q=Quantum%20Programmer))

The technology needs to progress significantly before it really means anything.  But I've never seen that stop the marketing department from leveraging a good buzzword.

Comment: But they're calling themselves quantum programmers because the results of their work is indeterminate.

Comment: And as long as you don't turn on the monitor the software is both working and not working at the same time.